# Very light linux for 3GB Laptop to build pentest lab

Tags: server

I am trying to have as more operating systems as I can on my virtual machine to create a virtual lab for my research, but my Laptop isn't able to make four or more heavy OS working together, especially when running Kali or Ubuntu it really need lot of RAM and CPU, I have only 3GB and running a Ubuntu 14.4.

If there is a ready "http server" light distro that will be great.

So can anyone help me with some very light distro of Linux (Ubuntu like distro) that doesn't look so unfamiliar.

Comment: We only support and help with official Ubuntu versions. Distributions like Kali are off topic. If you want a general answer, so not specific to using Ubuntu, you need to ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ The question about what to install is too generic and already been thoroughly answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem using Ubuntu. Create a VM with 512MB RAM, install Ubuntu server without anything else and then add apache (or nginx or lighttp.) Should work fine without really using that much resources.

Alternatively check out Puppy Linux or Ubuntu snappy.